# Resources for learning Greenlandic?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, greenlandic

[Greenlandic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_language) is an Eskimo-Aleut language with approximately 56.200 speakers (according to a survey dating from 2007). It has several dialects, including West Greenlandic or Kalaallisut, which is the official language of Greenland. Since it is such a small language, finding resources for learning it is a bit more challenging than usual. Therefore, any type of learning resource would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

- [Poplanguage: Greenlandic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wU5qhAfRUBA) is a YouTube video by Ben DuMonde that gives a short introduction on the history and characteristics of Greenlandic. It is not a learning resource as such but provides some background before you start learning.
- [How to Learn Greenlandic: A Resource Guide](https://worldwithlittleworlds.com/2018/06/21/how-to-learn-greenlandic-a-resource-guide/) is a longish blogpost from June 2018 that goes far beyond the previous video.
- [Greenlandic conversation](http://brazil1500.tripod.com/wodlingos/id33.html) provides some basic vocabulary and phrases with translation. It seems that the site is no longer being maintained, since the links to the sound files (on a different server) no longer work.
- [Greenlandic for Foreigners](https://learngreenlandic.com/course-material/what-is-on-the-dvd/) is "a course material originally developed for self study, but more often used in combination with physical teaching." The materials require local installation on Microsoft Windows or Mac OS, so if you use Linux, you are out of luck. The materials were developed by LearnGreenlandic, an organisation that offers Greenlandic language courses in English and Danish (but actually mainly in Danish).
- [Learn Greenlandic](http://learngreenlandic.tumblr.com/) is a course on Tumblr by someone who is learning Greenlandic. [Learn Greenlandic on Memrise)(https://www.memrise.com/course/906807/learn-greenlandic/) helps you learn the vocabulary in this course.
- [Learn Greenlandic](http://learn101.org/greenlandic.php) on learn101.org has online lessons that introduce the Greenlandic alphabet, basic grammar, common phrases and important vocabulary.
- [Learn Greenlandic](http://www.ilanguages.org/greenlandic.php) in iLanguage.org is a similar resource but has more audio resources (i.e. for the pronunciation of individual words).
- [Resources for Greenlandic (Kalaallisut)?](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/18623583/Resources-for-Greenlandic-Kalaallisut) is a thread on DuoLingo that was started in 2017.